# Cannot fetch data in view #codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Whats wrong wth my code?

This is my controller

```
//...
function index()
    {
        $data['tampilkan'] = $this->mymodel->tampil();
        $this->load->view('client/homepage', $data);
    }
//...
```

This is my model

```
//...
function tampil()
    {
        $this->db->select("id_konfirmasi,atas_nama_konfirmasi,jumlah"); 
        $this->db->from('konfirmasi'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        return $query->result(); 
    }
//...
```

And this is my view

```
//...
<?php
             if (!empty($tampilkan)):
               foreach ($tampilkan as $row): ?>

                   <span class="label label-success">New Donatur</span> <?php echo $row->atas_nama_konfirmasi; ?> Send us <?php echo $row->jumlah; ?><br/>


               <?php endforeach;
                else:
                    echo "No donatur";
                endif
            ?>
//...
```

Why always show "No donatur". in my tables have 2 donatur. Pls help

Comment: Is your model for tampil(); method is autoloaded in your config? Check it first.

Comment: i"ll check it...

Comment: already at autoload .this $autoload['model'] = array('mymodel');

Comment: specify codeigniter version you are using and also provide model name

Comment: print `$data['tampilkan'] ` in your controller and check. `print_r($data['tampilkan'] ); exit;` in your controller

Comment: Check your error Logs and share errors.

Comment: @dhruvjadia version 3.0.0

Comment: @YadhuBabu already add print_r($data['tampilkan'] ); exit; at my controller, but no chances

Comment: what is name of your model ?

Comment: @dhruvjadia mymodel

Comment: are you have data in your controller or you not able to fetch data from db? if you didn't have data in your controller replace the data method in your model to this `return $query->result_array()`

Comment: Thanks, already solved, i just make my controller function as array. Thanks very much all

Answer (score 0):

on function tampil()   replace `return $query->result();` with

```
return $query->result_array();
```

OR... second option (that's how I write code)

on function tampil()   replace `return $query->result();` with

```
 return $query;
```

then in view replace   `foreach ($tampilkan as $row):` with

```
foreach($tampilkan->result_array() as $row):
```